# How to change the rejection rate (or any parameter for that matter) with respect to time in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have a use case on a manufacturing line, where the rejection rate changes with time;
for example, in Week one rejection rate is 80% and in week 2 rejection rate is 60%.
How can i achieve this in anylogic.

I have created a very simple model;

[My model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BKxw.png)

After the machine, I added a **decision station** where i have defined the **probability of rejection**.
I am not sure how to change the probability of rejection based on time,
for example, in Week one rejection rate is 80% and in week 2 rejection rate is 60%.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3z8W.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are tons of different ways to do it.

Simplest option (seems you are a beginner):

replace your probability with a 1-line code statement such as:

```
time(WEEK) <= 1 ? 0.8 : 0.6
```

Beyond that, check out full functions, custom distributions, table functions, database calls...

AnyLogic really enables "any logic" :D

Comment: Thanks for this Benjamin! I will explore more based on your suggestions!

Comment: If the answer was useful, pls upvote it, helps future users with similar issues. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote